# Kafka using a distant Zookeeper instance?

Tags: zookeeper, kafka

we have an existing Zookeeper instance, and want to build a Kafka cluster in a remote location (not on the same side of the Atlantic ocean).

Can we use that existing Zookeeper for our new Kafka usage ?
Would latency be an issue ? Kafka is using Zookeeper for storing and distributing configuration, which may not be subject to latency issues, but it's hard to tell. Does anyone have experience in that ?

thanks